# GeoServer GetLegendGraphic in different Languages using SLD

Tags: geoserver, sld, internationalization, getlegendgraphic

I am trying generate Legend Graphic in different languages from GeoServer SLD. I came across this GeoServer documentation [i18N in SLD](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/language.html)

Where in the title tag we can specify the localized tag with different languages and when we request with LANGUAGE param in URL it should provide title of the style in specified language. But while trying to create style using this localized tag in title, I am getting error
Element 'se:Title' is a simple type, so it must have no element information item [children]
Below is the sample SLD. Is there any way I can get the legends in different different languages from same style?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1.0">
      <NamedLayer>
        <se:Name>Cyclone_Hazard_Zone</se:Name>
        <UserStyle>
          <se:Name>Cyclone_Hazard_Zone</se:Name>
          <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
            <se:Rule>
              
              <se:Name>Lake</se:Name>
              
              <se:Description>
                <!--<se:Title>Lake1</se:Title>-->
                <se:Title>Lake1
                  <Localized lang="en">English title</Localized>
                  <Localized lang="it">Titolo in italiano</Localized>
                </se:Title>
              </se:Description>
              <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>Lake</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Filter>
              <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#01C5FF</se:SvgParameter>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">1</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                
              </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            </se:Rule>
       </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: where do you get the error? if it is just a validation error then just ignore it and the legend should work.

Comment: Yes, Legends are coming.. but only with default title only. No change even after passing Language in the request

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you are using SLD 1.1, Style internationalization is supported in SLD 1.0 only.

As a rule of thumb, try not to use SLD 1.1 in GeoServer, while compatible, it supports a subset of the functionality provided by SLD 1.0 along with GeoServer extensions, like the one you're trying to use.

In particular, SLD 1.1 Title is a simple string, the SLD 1.1 parser and schema were not extended to support the Localized sub-element, like the SLD 1.0 parser was.